# How to differentiate the admin and front end in laravel4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, bundle

I have just started to work on laravel 4. I need to make differentiate the admin and fornt.

Like `AdminController.php` and `FrontController.php` in codeigniter. Is it possible in `laravel4` or any other technique?

Thanks

Comment: Of course it is. Just create master controllers for front end and backend. Exactly like you said.

Answer (score 2):

You could create separate controllers, or you could create a different bundle/package for each

see the docs http://laravel.com/docs/packages